# Django-admin page is missing select all checkbox on deploy

Tags: python, django, django-deployment

I've deployed my Django project on DigitalOcean.com. I've set static folder and run `python manage.py collectstatic` which worked correctly. The only problem is that I can't see select all checkbox in admin page.

This is in my local Django project:

[image]

And this is in deployed project:

[image]

I can't figure out where the problem is. Do you know?

I'm attaching `settings.py` of deployed project:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'some key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [


    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django_tables2',
    'import_export',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'drevo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'drevo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME':'/home/django/drevo/db.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd'

ADMIN_EMAIL = 'email@gmail.com'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

VARS_MODULE_PATH = 'main_app.global_variables.py'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/drevo/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: just to make sure, you are using the same django version both locally and in production, right?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Probably yes, I've checked it. It's 1.10.0

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I've checked it and I saw 1.10.0 there but settings.py says that: Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.7.

Comment: The settings are originaly from my local project.

Comment: Try to make the versions the same and see the result.

Comment: I'm trying to install 1.9.7 on the server but it doesn't work since there are differences between versions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it **backing up all data in my static folder, emptying it** and executing again:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I figured out it was because of static files from a previous app I had installed (django-grappelli). Django was trying to move file needed to the destination /static/ folder, but as there were already the same files created by django-grapelli it just ignored them and doesn't moved them. Example:

```
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/dashboard.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

Emptying the folder I forced the command to recopy everything bak there and everything worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue (at least same effects). It turned out to be (I think) a cache issue, either on nginx or on the client browser:

My production server works with Debian jessie, nginx, gunicorn, Django 1.10.2 + SSL.

To test if you have a cache problem, run (if your prod server allows this)

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

(or any other port you can access) on your production server for a short while. And test there if the checkbox is present. If yes, than just restart your server services and force the browser cache refresh a few times (hit shift+click on the refresh arrow on most of the browser I know).